# Lots of Hikari pool threads being created

Tags: hikaricp

In my java application, I am noticing lots of hikari pool threads (around 250 ) being created even if I have set the limit to be 25.
My java application ran out of memory and got stuck. When I did jstack, I see the following hikari pool threads numbered from 1-250.
HikariPool-1, HikariPool-2 .. HikariPool-250.
So, the question is why so many hikaripool threads got created?
Also, I see the following warnings too
"Thread starvation or clock leap detected"
Does anyone have any idea on what might be going on here?