# Spring Boot - How to disable auto create unused threads when start pod

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, threadpool

As the below setting.
When start the service. The server will create 900 threads as max limit.
But all created threads is sleep.

How can I set the server not auto create unused threads? I want it create thread when really have needs and keep using minimum resources.

```
spring-open-session-in-view=false
spring.datasource.max-lifetime=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-idle=100
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=900
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=10000
```

Comment: This has been asked before, but was not answered, see [Lots of Hikari pool threads being created](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69023959/11934850).

Comment: How did you count the number of threads? When I look at the Hikary code, the two Excecutors to add and remove Connections start with just one Thread (core size = maximum size = 1). The connections will be stored in a LinkedBlockingQueue. Each Connection needs one thread, there are no additional threads involved. So if you got 900 threads from the connection pool, there must be 900 connections. Have you logged pool behaviour by setting logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool to DEBUG? What was the output?

Comment: I check MySQL workbench -> Client Connections. 
Before I start the pod. Already created 1129 threads and 9xx connected.
When I start the pod. The threads connected will show 1024. same with connection limit number.
Even I turn off the pod. The threads still connected 9xx.
All Threads but 2 localhost is sleep.

Comment: MySQL workbench displays the *database* not the service. The configuration in the question is the service configuration. The service can only have threads, when the process  (=the pod) is running. I don't see evidence that the pod starts too many threads.